# remove repeated users from rank with group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to rank from a table `users`. This table contains a log of all results. I already can rank the elements depending on the result ASC, but I have repeated users ID that I want to group by but I can't.

```
ID_competitionLog   ID_event    ID_athlete  result  wind    rank    
4                        19                2            49.12   NULL     1
6                        19                11           49.56   NULL     2
13                       19                1            50.12   NULL     4
17                       4                 1            49.8    NULL     3
```

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( result, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( result ORDER BY result ASC )
FROM competitionlog where (ID_event = 19 or ID_event = 4) and (result <> 0.0125 and result <> 0.00125 and result <> 0.000125))) AS rank
FROM competitionlog where (ID_event = 19 or ID_event = 4) and (result <> 0.0125 and result <> 0.00125 and result <> 0.000125);
```

I try to group by the repeated users and get only theirs best result to compare in the ranking

Comment: Please take a few minutes and format your question so that others may read it.

Comment: Why aren't you using rank window function? also please add sample data as text.